Get ISO 8601 without milliseconds
I need to get the current date as ISO 8601 without milliseconds.
Annotation 6 of learn microsoft states for style 127:

For a milliseconds (mmm) value of 0, the millisecond decimal fraction value won't display. For example, the value 2022-11-07T18:26:20.000 displays as 2022-11-07T18:26:20.

I have following query:
select
    getdate() as current_datetime,
    datepart(millisecond, getdate()) as ms_of_current_dt,
    dateadd(millisecond, -datepart(millisecond, getdate()), getdate()) as current_dt_without_ms,
    convert(varchar, dateadd(millisecond, -datepart(millisecond, getdate()), getdate() at time zone 'Central European Standard Time'), 127) as current_dt_as_iso8601

It doesn't always work:



current_datetime
ms_of_current_dt
current_dt_without_ms
current_dt_as_iso8601




2024-09-25 17:01:21.697
696
2024-09-25 17:01:21.000
2024-09-25T15:01:21.001Z



Sometimes I get .001 of milliseconds.
What can I do? I guess datepart() is too accurate. Is there a function that returns the current date and time as datetime2?

Is there a function that returns the current date and time as datetime2? - yes, use SYSDATETIME() and assign it to a DATETIME2 variable or column

And if you want a string based value (you really don't) then the problem is you are declaring a varchar without (length). A varchar(19) doesnt' have space to display milliseconds. The documentation you link actually tells you about this "feature": "When converting from datetime or smalldatetime values, use an appropriate char or varchar data type length to truncate unwanted date parts."

@ThomA but also not the space to display the Z

CONCAT/+ @complete_stranger

The multiple references to both getdate() in your original query and sysdatetime() in your revised query aren't guaranteed to evaluate to the same time. Each reference is treated as a runtime constant and will be the same for all rows but the references are evaluated independently

Just CONVERT the current SYSUTCDATETIME to a varchar of the appropriate length to the appropriate style; 19 and 127 respectively. Then you can concatenate the Z at the end:
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(19), SYSUTCDATETIME(),127)+'Z';

Alternatively, use a varchar(20) and cast SYSDATETIMEOFFSET to a datetimeoffset(0):
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0), SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()),127);

db<>fiddle

With the information of SYSDATETIME() I was able to solve it with this query:
select convert(varchar(20), dateadd(nanosecond, -datepart(nanosecond, sysdatetime()), sysdatetime() at time zone 'Central European Standard Time'), 127) as current_dt_as_iso8601

Additional information: at time zone 'Central European Standard Time' is necessary otherwise one doesn't get the Z at the end. Maybe the time zone has to be adjusted in other cases.

This is grossly overly complicated. "Additional information: at time zone 'Central European Standard Time' is necessary otherwise one doesn't get the Z at the end" This isn't really true; the AT TIME ZONE isn't necessary, and using Central European Standard Time is more confusing as it's not UTC, despite you wanting a UTC time. The Z is added because you are now using a datetimeoffset rather than a datetime2. If you wanted a datetimeoffset then use SYSDATETIMEOFFSET instead.

Not to mention, as Martin Smith states, this could end up wrong still, due to the 2 calls to SYSDATETIME.
